# Test SSL before changing DNS

Tags: ssl, nginx

I setup a new server.
Before I change the nameservers of the domain to the new server, I would like to test if the SSL is correctly installed. 
Is there a possibility for this?
I'm using Nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you can test the SSL before changing the domain record.

assume you want to test SSL with domain `www.example.com`, Nginx config should like following:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate your-ssl-crt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key your-private-key.key;
    ...
}
```

and assume your server IP is `192.0.2.78`. by updating a file named `hosts` at `/etc/hosts`(change the file on your client, not the server)
, you will be able to browse `www.example.com` which served by `192.0.2.78`.

You need to use root permission to change the host file by command `sudo vim /etc/hosts`, add a new line:

```
192.0.2.78 www.example.com
```

Now you can test whether your SSL work via `https://www.example.com`

Comment: So I have to edit this on a Ubuntu client? This cannot be done from a Windows pc?

Comment: @user3605780 on Windows you'll have to edit file `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and then run `ipconfig /flushdns` to apply changes (all this operations must be done from administrator).

Comment: It worked however in Chrome I'm getting the error that the certificate cannot be validated. "This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).". I can just click ignore and it is secured "The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2 (a strong protocol), ECDHE_RSA with X25519 (a strong key exchange), and AES_256_GCM (a strong cipher).". 
Is this showing because I check it using this method, or did I install it incorrectly?

Comment: I copied the files:
    ssl_certificate your-ssl-crt_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key your-private-key.key;
To the new server.
Or do I need to create a new certificate per server where I'm using it?